# Windows Forms - how to call an event of child form from a parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, events

I have `MDI form` project and a form called `BaseForm` which inherits from `Form` and all the other forms including the `MDIparent` inherit from this `BaseForm`. Some of my child forms can be edited so I have `Save` button. I also ask for save on the parent's form `closing event` if there are open editable child forms. I do it like this:

```
 protected void IsEditable()
        {
            foreach (BaseForm f in MdiChildren)
            { 
                if (f.isEditable == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("To Do Save" + f.GetType().ToString());
                    f.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

The question is that I have already implemented once the `save` logic for the chilren's `Save button on click` event. I don't want to write the same code again, so is there any way to call the event(that hold the saving logic) from the code above. The check if the form is editable is made in the `BaseForm` Form.

Comment: So you have a base type and you want to be able to call some member methods from the inherited type. Is this correct ?

Comment: even I am not sure of the question....pretty much confused with form names actually...

Comment: @TheKingDave - sorry for not being very clear. It's right I want to call a method and more specificly an event from my parent. I wonder if this is possible when all events are private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refractor the code in the `SaveButton_Click` to call a Method called `SaveForm()`, make this method public, and:

```
protected void IsEditable()
    {
        foreach (ChildForm f in MdiChildren)
        { 
            if (f.isEditable == true)
            {
                f.SaveForm();
                f.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```